# How do I modify the instruction pointer from a handler function in Windows/MASM?

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86-64, masm, seh

I want to use an exception/trap handler from assembly, but I don't know how to actually modify the context of the offending frame.

My code:

```
_TEXT segment para 'CODE'
    MyHandler proc
        call printout
        ret
    MyHandler endp

    public SyntaxTest
    SyntaxTest proc frame:MyHandler
        .endprolog
        ud2
        .beginepilog
        ret
    SyntaxTest endp
_TEXT ends
```

Right now, when `ud2` is executed, the code jumps to `MyHandler`, calls the `printout` function (implemented elsewhere), then resumes execution in the exact same spot, creating an infinite loop. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

`MyHandler` (function in *FRAME :ehandler-address* ) this is so called [Language-specific handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=msvc-170#language-specific-handler) . so it must have signature:

```
EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION __cdecl MyHandler(
    _In_ PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord,
    _In_ void * EstablisherFrame,
    _Inout_ PCONTEXT ContextRecord,
    _Inout_ PDISPATCHER_CONTEXT DispatcherContext
    );
```

if you want continue execution - you must return `ExceptionContinueExecution` and **modify** `ContextRecord` - the `Rip` ( say `Rip += 2` for skip `ud2` ). the `printout` probably return 0, but you not fix `Rip` as result the `ud2` executed again. the absolute minimum, demo only code

```
CONTEXT STRUCT 16
    _P1Home DQ ?;
    _P2Home DQ ?;
    _P3Home DQ ?;
    _P4Home DQ ?;
    _P5Home DQ ?;
    _P6Home DQ ?;

    ;
    ; Control flags.
    ;

    _ContextFlags DD ?;
    _MxCsr DD ?;

    ;
    ; Segment Registers and processor flags.
    ;

    _SegCs DW ?;
    _SegDs DW ?;
    _SegEs DW ?;
    _SegFs DW ?;
    _SegGs DW ?;
    _SegSs DW ?;
    _EFlags DD ?;

    ;
    ; Debug registers
    ;

    _Dr0 DQ ?;
    _Dr1 DQ ?;
    _Dr2 DQ ?;
    _Dr3 DQ ?;
    _Dr6 DQ ?;
    _Dr7 DQ ?;

    ;
    ; Integer registers.
    ;

    _Rax DQ ?;
    _Rcx DQ ?;
    _Rdx DQ ?;
    _Rbx DQ ?;
    _Rsp DQ ?;
    _Rbp DQ ?;
    _Rsi DQ ?;
    _Rdi DQ ?;
    _R8 DQ ?;
    _R9 DQ ?;
    _R10 DQ ?;
    _R11 DQ ?;
    _R12 DQ ?;
    _R13 DQ ?;
    _R14 DQ ?;
    _R15 DQ ?;

    ;
    ; Program counter.
    ;

    _Rip DQ ?;
CONTEXT ENDS

.code
MyHandler proc
    add [r8][CONTEXT._Rip],2
    xor eax,eax
    ret
MyHandler endp


SyntaxTest proc frame:MyHandler
    .endprolog
    ud2
    .beginepilog
    ret
SyntaxTest endp
end
```

of course in real code need analyze source of exeption, and select what need todo based on this. but not hardcode `rip += 2` and continue.